# Hot to make Facebook play videos with HTML5 player

Tags: video, flash, facebook, opera

I'm using latest Opera on Kubuntu 16.10. For some time all chromium based browser abandoned support for flash player (including pepperflashplayer). As HTML5 players are more and more used that shouldn't be an issue. But, for some reason, when I try to play a video on Facebook it reports an error that Flash is unavailable even though Facebook claims to use HTML5 player.

I'm able to play videos e. g. on YouTube. I'm also able to play Facebook videos in Chromium.

Anyone had a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: AFAIK they haven't abandoned Flash. Try to install [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Comment: I found information about HTML5 player in here: https://code.facebook.com/posts/159906447698921/why-we-chose-to-move-to-html5-video/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does it work now for you?

Comment: I installed adobe-flashplugin as you suggested and it worked! Actually, I'm surprised. I thought chromium-based browsers abandoned the API which supported flash plugins. Anyway, thanks for help!